# JSONP Utncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsonp

I need to create a simple HTTP GET request to an intracom.

The request opens a door. If I enter this url in my browser: 
http://172.27.1.20/api/switch/ctrl?switch=1&action=on
the port opens and the browser shows it.

```
{
"success" : true
}
```

I try to use a Ajax script to send the HTTP GET but the console log shows:

```
ctrl?callback=jQuery1600571…_1473684252251&switch=1&action=on&_=1473685494405:2 Utncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected oken :
 function test() {              
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://172.27.1.20/api/switch/ctrl',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {switch: 1, action: 'on'},
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                dataCharset: 'jsonp',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                console.log("OK - RESULT: " + result);
               },
                error: function (result, error) {
                console.log("ERROR - RESULT: " + result + " - TYPE ERROR: " + error);
                }
            });
        }
```

someone can helpme?

Comment: I use jsonp because i need use it from another domain.

Comment: You can accept the answer below if it has helped?

Answer (score 0):

Why are using jsonp? Is that really required? If you use JSONP, must set callback function in response. I dont see your callback function in url?

change url & add callback function

```
url: http://172.27.1.20/api/switch/ctrl?switch=1&action=on&callback=yourCallbackFunctionName
```

When JSONP server receives your request and finds callback parameter - instead of returning plain JS array it'll return this:

```
yourCallbackFunctionName({['success', 'true']});
```

Now in your code try to read the data - sample ( not tested ) code below

```
success: function(dataSentInJsonp){
                        var len = dataSentInJsonp.length;
                        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                            // iterate and get your variables
                              valVariable= dataSentInJsonp[i];
                          }
```